# uiwebview's displacement value after focus & keyboard appearance

Tags: objective-c, uiwebview, calayer, uikeyboard

I have UIWebView among with other UI elements on the screen. After I click on textfield inside a webview, whole webview is moving up (it is moving webview content, not a webview containter, right?). Is there possibility to find a displacement value after showing up a keyboard to move other elements as well? I am getting uiwebview's layer position values before/after keyboard appereance but there are not seeming to be changing...

btw. what's, in short, difference between layer and frame?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

My solution:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(resize:) name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification object:nil];

(void) test
{
    CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0,0,320,460);
    self.webView.scrollView.bounds = rect;
}

(void) resize:(id)sender
{
    [self performSelector:@selector(test) withObject:nil afterDelay:0];
}
```

Comment: How could it help me? It's blocking scrollview after first entry to textfield.